# jQuery table sort with colspan or rowspan

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter, html-table

**Hi**

I'm using ***tablesorter*** and have problems with sorting tables that contain ***rowspan*** in  definition.
I've read hints here [Grouping Rows with Client Side HTML Table Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509690)
but solution doesn't work when I have different values for rowspan: once is rowspan=3, once 4 - depends on data taken from DB.

Do you have any other plugin that sorts even such non-standard tables or maybe you know how to tune ***tablesorter*** so it sorts data properly?

Expected behaviour: when clicked on column, rows "belonging" to rowspan should be sorted within this section only, all the others - in a standard way.

**Thanks in advance**,

Zbigniew

Table code example:

```
<html>
<body>
  <table id="misint" border=1 width="400px">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background:yellow">
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3">1-1</td>
          <td>1-2</td>
          <td>1-3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2-2</td>
            <td>2-3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3-2</td>
            <td>3-3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4-1</td>
            <td>4-2</td>
            <td>4-3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5-1</td>
          <td rowspan="2">5-2</td>
          <td>5-3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6-1</td>
            <td>6-3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give some example markup?

Comment: Have you solved this problem, if yes, please provide some solution or idea, I am also having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the parser functionality of table sorter. You'll need to develop your own parser that will be able to recognize the cells properly.